# How the button can also acts like a link

Tags: reactjs, button, hyperlink

I want to create a button that also acts as a link. I want that because I have a form in my header, this form is multi-form actually so when the user clicked on the button I want it to redirect to another page and also continues to the second step of the form.

So basically, I have UserForm which is my parent form, and I have InstantQuote form which is in the header of the home page.

```
<button type="submit" className="btn button" onClick={this.continue}>
          Details
          <BsArrowRightShort />
        </button>
```

So I want to add something to this button to redirect to another page and at the same time continues to the form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Usually, you do this in a stepper. It means you switch between forms, but keep data locally and submit it only once.

Comment: you could either, as suggested below style an <a> tag as a button, or use a react router to push a new url (that then redirects your browser)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using button tag you can use an a tag and you can give the a tag the style which you wanted your button tag get.

```html
<a href="#" className="btn button" onClick={this.continue}>
      Details
    <BsArrowRightShort />
</a>
```